# how to modify array_count_values output

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array

```
$array=(1,1,2,3,3,3,4);
```

i need to find each element how many times each element is exist in array .

So that i use

```
$occurences = array_count_values($array);
```

output is

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 1
)
```

But  i need to arrage the out put in following format

```
1 : 2
2 : 1
3 : 3
4 : 1
```

how can i do that ?

is there an other solution rater than using `array_count_values`

please help ;

Comment: Your question is not clear for me what you mean under `but i need to arrange this in table . But atleast i need to arrage this in` ? you want to `echo` output like `1 : 2` `2:1` .. or build array with that values ... OR ?

Comment: what table is intended?

Comment: Do you want HTML `<table>` and row for every occurance?

Comment: Please read the question once again. I modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over every occurance and `echo` them out.

```
// If they are in wrong order, sort your array
ksort($occurences);

// Print output
if(count($occurences)>0){
  foreach ($occurences as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

To sort by no of occurances, use [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

```
arsort($occurences);
```

Of course, before printing it.

If `2:1` must come before `4:1` in your case, use:

```
asort($occurences);
arsort($occurences);
```

Comment: Could you please tell how to arrange this based on the number of times occurring . ie in acceding or descending order . like I need to display like this 3:3 , 1:2 , 2:1 , 4:1

Answer (score 0):

Just use this loop to have output like you need

```
foreach ($occurences as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k : $v <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode` or `array_keys` and `array_values`

```
<?php 

$array= array(1,1,2,3,3,3,4);
$occurences = array_count_values($array);

$array_keys = array_keys($occurences);
$array_values = array_values($occurences);

for($i=0; $i<count($array_keys); $i++) {
    echo $array_keys[$i].':'.$array_values[$i].'\n';//add \n or \br tag
}

//you can echo json_encode
echo json_encode($occurences);
```